# there is a python file where there are variables and it should be changed from another python file, just for some reason it doesn't go

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

There is a python file where there are variables and it should be changed from another python file, just for some reason it doesn't go

I did it small, which was in my project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Y2i.jpg

Comment: you are changing the value at runtime and not writing the file. hence not reflecting

Comment: Thank you! and how can i do this? (I tried with a = open(....) .... , but it was wrong, because it appended a new line with code). So I think there is better way, just i didn't find. Do you know it? and thank you very much

Comment: It is better to post your code in text format rather than posting it as an image!

Comment: oke thank you i will

Comment: Maybe environmental variables will be more suitable for you? Look at os.getenv and os.setenv.